# Creating lines that can be modified from ends

Tags: three.js

So I'd like to create some lines that can be modified from points that are connecting them.

An example of initial state

[image]

First one has been moved down, second one up and third one right and down.

On the implementation side I currently have two meshes. First one is stretched out so that it would cover the distance from its starting point to the next point and second one marks the starting point.

```
var meshLine = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
meshLine.position.set(x,y,z);
meshLine.scale(1,1,distancetonextpoint);

var meshPoint = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, material);
meshPoint.position.set(x,y,z);
meshPoint.scale(2,2,2);
```

What I want from it is that when the user drags the circular point other lines would stretch or change their position accordingly to the one being dragged.

Is there some more reasonable solution for this as I feel mine is not quite good and clean. I'd have to do quite heavy lifting to get the movement done.

I've also looked at [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_lines.html) which looks visually very nice but could not integrate it to my system.

Comment: do you mean edit the line/object when dragging its vertices ?

Comment: @Astrak yes, guess I explained it badly :)

Comment: what about [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Astrak/b05m3Lqg/) (click on 'resize mode' to toggle to 'edit mode') : you can change the geometry by dragging the vertices. Is that what you need ?

Comment: @Astrak this looks nice, I'm gonna dig deep tommorrow. I need something similar and I'm sure I can get some good ideas from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you need to edit the object's geometry by dragging their vertices (here a line).

1. Objects'vertices can't be dragged theirselves, so you need to loop through the geometry and create little spheres at each vertex position ;
2. You set a raycaster to pick those spheres, as in the examples ;
3. Your screen is 2D so to drag objects in 3D you need a surface perpendicular to the screen, that intersects the sphere position. For this you set an invisible plane at the vertex position and make it look at the camera ;
4. Once you can correctly drag the spheres, you tell the corresponding vertices on the object (your lines) they must keep the same position as their spheres ;
5. End with `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true`.

And you have your new geometry

- For code details on picking objects look at the official picking objects'example [draggable cubes](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html)
- [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/Atrahasis/b05m3Lqg/) shows how to use it for editing objects

Comment if you need more explanations